# Фреймворк для ввода таблиц

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

Есть ли какие-нибудь приличные js-фреймворки для фронтенда для создания таблиц в браузере? Для вывода таблиц их много, а для ввода не нашёл.

Comment: что такое таблица в вашем понимании? опишите весь желаемый функционал

Comment: Таблица - набор данных в матричной форме, который можно вывести в `<table>`. Из функционала требуется возможность минимально редактировать данные (добавлять строчки-столбцы, менять содержимое ячеек) и передавать это на сервер. Нужно для создания админки, чтобы админ мог изменять таблицу размеров на продукты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Довольно удобный вот этот http://www.jeasyui.com/, легко подключается, может работать на минимуме html5 и jquery. Работаю с ней уже 3 месяца!)

Answer (score 1):

я сейчас изучаю [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com), не плохая штука, может и выводить, и редактировать, и делать групповые копи-пасты и драгэнддропы, сортировки, удалять, добавлять строки, отправлять данные на бэк энд, только я вот не разобрался, как добавлять строку между строками, а так уже в принципе работаю и неплохо, только там есть урезанная community версия, и платная enterprise, но функции enterprise не заблокированы, поэтому можно эксперементировать.